# When is the "comfort women" statue in Ashfield Uniting Church accessible?

Tags: australia, religion, sydney, history

When is the "comfort women" statue in Ashfield Uniting Church in Sydney accessible to the public? In particular, is it publicly accessible on weekday evenings?

[A news article about the statue](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-12-14/japanese-group-launches-18c-case-against-uniting-church/8117234) says that it's located at Ashfield Uniting Church. According to this page about [Uniting Church parish missions](http://nswact.uca.org.au/community/parish-missions/), the website for the Ashfield Parish Mission is http://ashfieldparishmission.com.au/ , which isn't working. I can see a sign with info about the church via [Google Street View](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@-33.8900576,151.1274592,3a,15y,211.73h,87.91t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sqdKHe_9dbZxpYRcxR7G1sQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1), but the resolution is too poor to read the information.

[Whereis](http://www.whereis.com/nsw/ashfield-2131/yellowId-13272118) and Google businesses (or whatever it's called) doesn't have any opening times either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Only during the day (working) hours - not the evening, unfortunately.**

Two sources:

**Their (down) website**

Using Google's Cache of http://www.exodusfoundation.org.au/about/parish from December 7th of this year, it notes that:

> The congregation of the Ashfield Uniting Church Parish Mission meets
>   every Sunday at 10:00am at 180 Liverpool Road, Ashfield, with
>   Communion held on the first Sunday of each month.

So on Sunday mornings, at least, you'd certainly have access to the grounds.

**Via a phone call**

**Update**: Spoke to their receptionist. The statue is on the grounds, around the back of the church. **Access to the grounds is from 7am-5pm daily**, so unfortunately, not viewable in the evenings, but during the day you can go any day of the week.

Note that over the Christmas period they have a large tent up for an event, so might obscure some angles for photography, if that's your purpose.